# How do I prove this in natural deduction calculus?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

My premises are:

1. $\forall x(x\in A \leftrightarrow(x=R \lor \exists y(y\in A \land x=y^{+1})))$
2. $\forall p\forall r\forall x(\langle p,r\rangle \in x^{+1} \leftrightarrow \exists q(\langle p,q\rangle\in x \land \langle q,r\rangle \in R))$
3. $\langle a,b\rangle\in R$
4. $\langle b,c\rangle \in B \land B\in A$

And, I want to prove the following:

- $\exists z(\langle a,c\rangle \in z \land z\in A)$

The symbols I am using are:

$$
\begin{array}{lr}
\text{2-place Predicate} & \in \\
\text{1-place Function} &  ^{+1} \\
\text{2-place Function} &  \langle \rangle \\
\text{Constants} & R,A,B,a,b,c
\end{array}
$$

### Meaning

We can have different meanings of the above premises and conclusion, but there is a primary meaning in my mind.

We can assume that the domain of discourse contains sets and other objects. So, we can think of $a$,$b$ and $c$ as some objects,$\langle a,b\rangle$ as an ordered pair and $R$ to be a set.

Premise (1) describes set $A$ recursively:

- $A$ is a set whose elements are only $R$,$R^{+1}$,$R^{+1+1}$,$R^{+1+1+1}$....

Premise (2),(3) and (4) says:

- For any set $x$, $x^{+1}$ is a set and it contains $\langle p,r\rangle$ iff there is a $q$, such that $\langle p,q\rangle$ belongs to $x$ and $\langle q,r\rangle$ belongs to $R$
- $R$ contains $\langle a,b\rangle$
- $B$ is a set containing $\langle b,c\rangle$. Also, $B$ belongs to $A$.

Now, the conclusion is saying
:

- There exists a $z$, such that $\langle a,c\rangle$ belongs to $z$ and $z$ belongs to $A$.

### Intuitive Explaination

As $B$ belongs to $A$, $B$ is equal to $R$ or $R^{+1}$ or $R^{+1+1}$ or $R^{+1+1+1}$... and for each value of $B$ we can show that the conclusion holds.

For example, assume $B=R^{+1+1}$

So, $\langle b,c\rangle$ belongs to $R^{+1+1}$ since $\langle b,c\rangle$ belongs to $B$

Since $\langle b,c\rangle$ belongs to $R^{+1+1}$, there exists a $d$ such that $\langle b,d\rangle$ belongs to $R^{+1}$ and $\langle d,c \rangle$ belongs to $R$ (by premise (2))

Since $\langle b,d \rangle$ belongs to $R^{+1}$, there exists a $e$ such that $\langle b,e\rangle$ belongs to $R$ and $\langle e,d\rangle$ belongs to $R$

Now, since $\langle a,b\rangle$ and $\langle b,e\rangle$ belongs to $R$, $\langle a,e\rangle$ belongs to $R^{+1}$

Since $\langle a,e \rangle$ belongs to $R^{+1}$ and $\langle e,d\rangle $ belongs to $R$, $\langle a,d\rangle$ belongs to $R^{+1+1}$

Since $\langle a,d\rangle$ belongs to $R^{+1+1}$ and $\langle d,c\rangle$ belongs to $R$, $\langle a,c\rangle$ belongs to $R^{+1+1+1}$

So, $\langle a,c\rangle$ belongs to $R^{+1+1+1}$ and $R^{+1+1+1}$ belongs to $A$

So, There exists a $z$, such that $\langle a,c\rangle$ belongs to $z$ and $z$ belongs to $A$.

### Where I am stuck

[image: I][image: u][image: e]

In the last step, I reached $C\in A \land B=C^{+1}$. Now, I should reach $C=R \lor \exists y(y\in A \land C=y^{+1}) $, I can prove the conclusion for $C=R$ case but for $\exists y (y\in A \land C=y^{+1} $, I have to introduce another constant $D$. But then again for $D$ I will get the case $\exists y(y\in A \land D=y^{+1})$ and so have to introduce another constant. So, I am stuck in '*infinite steps*'.

Comment: It seems a formula of set theory...

Comment: It is reasonable to have axioms for $⟨ \ldots ⟩$ and $^{+1}$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I mean, I don't really know if it is necessary to have axioms about them. It feels like the above two axioms are enough for proof.

Comment: the first "axiom" seems to assert that $A$ is a relation (in the set-theoretic sense) but it is not clear to me how this follows from $x=R$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Actually, yes the formulas are inspired from set theory. But there is nothing inherent about them that needs some axioms from set theory. A is actually not a relation, but a set of relations.

Comment: Maybe it helps if you write what is the intended meaning of axioms and purported theorem above...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ok, I will do so.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I have changed the premises and the conclusion a little bit so that the problem is more noticeable. I have added the meanings and some other things as well. If you have any other suggestions for the question you can tell me as well. Thanks

Comment: From the second conjunct of your line 29 and premise 2, you can go some steps further (replace $x$ with $B$ and instantiate with (p,r) = (b,c). But I have the impression that you need something more about $R$. I could be missing something...